# TypeError for list

Tags: python, string, list, nltk

I am using nltk, I tokenized my entire text file which has reviews, and stored it in a variable text:

```
with open("reviews.txt") as f:
     text=f.read()
```

Now, I tokenized the entire text in sentence tokenization.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

tokenized=sent_tokenize(text)
```

Now the entire tokenized data is in the form of sentence stored in `tokenized`

When I try to store this sentential tokenized data in a txt file I get a type error

```
with open("sentences.txt","w+") as f1:
     f1.write(tokenized)
```

I get type error when I execute it

```
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Comment: sent_tokenize(text) returns a list not str

Comment: "write" is expecting a string, and you are passing a list
You can join the content, i.e: f1.write(' '.join(tokenixed))

Answer (score 0):

## `sent_tokenize` returns a list of strings, not a string

Or in this context - sentence strings. If you wish to write them to a file, you should replace

```
with open("sentences.txt","w+") as f1:
     f1.write(tokenized)
```

With this code (assuming you wish to write one sentence per line):

```
with open("sentences.txt","w+") as f1:
     f1.write('\n'.join(tokenized))
```

Replace `'\n'` with your desirable sentence separator (comma `','` semicolon `';'` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to answer this in interactive mode.

- print(tokenized)
- help(f1.write)